# Store level User Permission In Magento Backend

Tags: magento2, php, multistore

I need to give saperate login for each store in magento 2,
I have two magento stores under one website, 
how can I give separate login for each store for admin users ?
It may be basic thing, but I new to magento, can't find out how to do this.
it will be great if anyone can help.
thanks

Comment: this functionality available only in EE edition

Comment: @KAndy thats not true. In magento 2 community you get that feature.

Comment: KAndy is right. There isn't configuration in Magento 2 CE to help you. Try this https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **Store > Settings > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options**.

There you'll be able to chose if you want your customers to have a different account given the website they're visiting or not.

If you use the default *Per Website* value, it'll mean that visitors will have to have a different account to visit your websites, if set to *Global* then they'll only need to have one account to visit all your websites.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, but I need access level for admin, I need to create multiple stores running, and every store admin area must be accessed by specifc user.

Comment: Dude, you've omitted that crucial point on your original question ... it's a whole other story.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, I edited the question and mention that login for admin users.do have any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this seems to be only available in the EE. This module claims to do the job. If you can trust this one is a different question.

[aitoc-advanced-permissions](https://marketplace.magento.com/aitoc-advanced-permissions.html)

Any suggestions on this topic would be helpfull since i got the same issue on the long run.

---

**Edit**

I actually hat to use the extension in one of our projects. For anything to do with customers and sales it works fine but we got some bugs with products and categories. In other sections it is not fully implemented as well but i guess you could extend it.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1/Magento 2, you can set user per store scope.
in Magento 2 you can do this by creating a new user Rule go to **System > Permissions > User Rules**.

Then change the Role scope in Role **Resources > Role Scopes** to the store you wish and then you can set custom access to specific areas of Magento by editing the **Resources > Role Resource**.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, when i go to roles->my role->role resources i cant find role scopes, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It should be there, it is in a drop down.

Comment: can confirm. i can't seem to find it in Mage 2.1.5. User role already saved too